# Is there a kdeedu package alternative in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, education, kde-apps

The package `kdeedu` is no longer available in Ubuntu 15.04. Is there an alternative to the `kdeedu` package in Ubuntu 15.04?

Prior to release 15.04, this package included a suite of KDE educational software including KWordQuiz, KAlgebra, Kalzium, KStars, Marble, etc.

I see that the following related packages are available in Vivid. Unfortunately, when I checked the contents of these packages, they do not include the applications that `kdeedu` used to include.

- `kdeedu-data`
- `kdeedu-kvtml-data`
- `libkdeedu-data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a list of the dependencies for kdeedu available in Ubuntu 14.10 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/kdeedu).  These individual packages are still available in Vivid, even though the kdeedu package is no longer in the repositories.

- blinken (>= 4:4.11.3) KDE version of the Simon electronic memory game
- cantor (>= 4:4.11.3) interface for mathematical applications
- kalgebra (>= 4:4.11.3) algebraic graphing calculator
- kalzium (>= 4:4.11.3) periodic table and chemistry tools
- kanagram (>= 4:4.11.3) jumble word puzzle
- kbruch (>= 4:4.11.3) fraction learning aid for KDE
- kgeography (>= 4:4.11.3) geography learning aid for KDE
- khangman (>= 4:4.11.3) Hangman word puzzle
- kig (>= 4:4.11.3) interactive geometry tool for KDE
- kiten (>= 4:4.11.3) Japanese reference and study aid for KDE
- klettres (>= 4:4.11.3) foreign alphabet tutor for KDE
- kmplot (>= 4:4.11.3) mathematical function plotter for KDE
- kstars (>= 4:4.11.3) desktop planetarium for KDE
- ktouch (>= 4:4.11.3) touch typing tutor for KDE
- kturtle (>= 4:4.11.3) educational programming environment
- kwordquiz (>= 4:4.11.3) flashcard learning program
- marble (>= 4:4.11.3) globe and map widget
- pairs (>= 4:4.11.3) memory and pairs game
- parley (>= 4:4.11.3) vocabulary trainer
- rocs (>= 4:4.11.3) graph theory IDE
- step (>= 4:4.11.3) interactive physical simulator for KDE

All of these packages can be installed in 15.04 using...

```
sudo apt-get install blinken cantor kalgebra kalzium kanagram kbruch kgeography khangman kig kiten klettres kmplot kstars ktouch kturtle kwordquiz marble pairs parley rocs step
```